# Pub/Sub client trying to publish to a different project ERROR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm tryint to test publishing a message into GCP usign PubSub and  I'm setting the project in the pubsubclient constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
        this.pubsub_client = new pubsub_1.PubSub({ projectId: "AAAAAA" });
        console.log(this.pubsub_client.projectId);
    }
```

And the function tu publish the message looks like this:

```
async publish(arg, refId) {
        const { queueIdentifier, payload } = arg;
        const meta_data = { refId: refId !== null && refId !== void 0 ? refId : Crypto_1.generateUlid(), time: UtilityProvider_1.getCurrentTimestamp() };

        try {
            const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(Object.assign({}, payload), { meta_data })));
            
            const topic = await this.pubsub_client.topic(queueIdentifier);
            const messageId = await topic
                .publishMessage({ data: dataBuffer });
            Logger_1.info("INFO", "Published to PubSub", { queueIdentifier, meta_data, messageId });
        }
        catch (error) {
            Logger_1.error("ERROR", "Failed to publish to PubSub", { error, queueIdentifier, meta_data });
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to publish a message I'm getting this error:

> Caller does not have required permission to use project
> BBBBBBBBBBBBB

being BBBBBBBB a different project that I don't even know. How is this possible?

I'm sure that the queue I'm trying to publish to is in the AAAAAA project and the credentials for gcloud are pointing to the same project AAAAAA so I have no clue from where the project BBBBB is coming. Any ideas?